# Is there a way to "extend" Capybara so that custom finders can be used?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I'm wondering if there is a way to create custom methods that allow me to "chain" calls against a Capybara object. This may be difficult to explain so here's an example that I'm trying to achieve:

`find('#element-id').some_custom_method_here`

`find('#another-element-id').some_custom_method_here`

`all('.other-class-id')[3].some_custom_method_here`

I'd like to be able to use custom class methods on a Capybara object, so that I might be able to find/manipulate/perform actions within a *specific* part of the DOM that might allow easy re-usability throughout a page.

The only way I've found myself being able to do this is by creating a function that passes the element first, and then moves on with my code. Like this:

```
def some_custom_method_here(capybara_obj, options={})
# do stuff with capybara_obj, find, click, etc
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option to achieve what you want, would be to once "wrap" or "decorate" your capybara object.

```
decorated_node = SomeCustomWrapper.new(find('#element-id'))
decorated_node.some_custom_method

class SomeCustomWrapper < SimpleDelegator
  def some_custom_method
    # do something with self
  end
end
```

If you need to do this a lot, you could also write yourself a method for finding decorated nodes:

```
def find_decorated(selector, options={})
  SomeCustomWrapper.new(find(selector, options))
end

def all_decorated(selector, options={})
  all(selector, options).map { |node| SomeCustomWrapper.new(node) }
end
```

If you really want to add functions to the instances of capybaras objects, you could monkey patch the relevant classes, namley: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element

But I would recommend against monkey-patching libraries whenever you can avoid it. In the end it will safe you only a couple of lines of code / add a little bit of convenience when writing, but it makes it much harder for others (or you in the future) to understand your code.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you could add methods to `Capybara::Node::Element` although you then risk breaking things if Capybara ever adds a method with the same name.  A safer solution would be to create a wrapper class that proxies methods through to the capybara element, implements to_capybara_node to allow Capybara expectations to work with the wrapped elements, and adds it's own methods too, along the lines of

```
class ElementWrapper
  def initialize(element)
    @capybara_element = element
  end

  def find(...)
    ElementWrapper.new(@capybara_element.find(...))
  end

  ... # wrap the rest of Capybara Elements methods to return wrapper objects

  def custom_method(...)
    implement custom method and return wrapped element if necessary
  end

  def to_capybara_node
    @capybara_element # return the native capybara element
  end
end
```

Then you'd have

```
ElementWrapper.new(page.find(...)).custom_method(...).find(...)
```

You could write your own find method in the namespace to remove the need for the ElementWrapper.new above.

Comment: That is exactly what [Capybara Test Helpers](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/) is doing, glad that you think it's a reasonable approach!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [**Capybara Test Helpers**](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/) to encapsulate your test code.

It will allow you to leverage the entire [Capybara DSL](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/api/), while creating your own [helpers](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/guide/essentials/actions) and [aliases](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/guide/essentials/aliases):

For example, [with RSpec](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/guide/essentials/injection.html#test-helpers-in-rspec):

```rb
RSpec.describe 'Sample', test_helpers: [:example] do
  scenario 'sample scenario' do
    example.element.some_custom_method_here
    example.another_element.some_custom_method_here
    example.all(:other_element)[3].some_custom_method_here
  end
end
```

And the implementation could be something like:

```rb
# test_helpers/example_test_helper.rb
class ExampleTestHelper < Capybara::TestHelper
  aliases(
    element: '#element-id',
    another_element: '#another-element-id',
    other_element: '.other-class-id',
  )

  def some_custom_method_here
    click # or any other Capybara command
  end
end
```

Any Capybara command that returns an element will be [automatically wrapped](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/guide/essentials/current-context), which simplifies chaining your [own methods or assertions](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/guide/essentials/assertions).